# get-pip.py raises ValueError when run in IDLE

Tags: python, windows, pip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHoE.png)I need to install PIP for Python 2.7.3.

I have run the *get-pip.py* file in Python IDLE shell. However, it raises the following exception:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': closed
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

How can fix this error?

Here is the error faced when trying to execute `python get-pip.py` in the command prompt:

[image]

[inspite of correct path no execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nyDJ.png)

Comment: Why did you install Python 2.7. **3** ?

Comment: thats the version compatible with ongoing work at my workplace.

Comment: if you have 2.7.9 - pip will automatically be installed, you just need to setup you PATH appropriately

Comment: have to work with python 2.7.3 only. can you please suggest a method for it

Comment: See [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) link from the linked page.

Comment: hi. that method of running get-pip.py is not getting executed. it raises error : Traceback (most recent call last):

ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': closed

Comment: answer to this problem has not been explained in the thread you mentioned

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to include [mcve] or ask a new question. The error message isn't very helpful.

Comment: hi. thank you for your input. have made the changes .can you please review the question now . :)

Comment: Are you running this from an elevated cmd.exe?

Comment: no. running it from python idle shell.

Comment: @summer93: how exactly do you execute it? Maybe you can include a screenshot? FWIW you aren't supposed to run it that way.

Comment: Then run it from an elevated cmd.exe…

Comment: @vaultah have added the screenshot. can you please explain why it should be run that way. thanks in advance,

Comment: @poke can you please explain how to do it as i do not have the administrator rights on the computer i am working on.

Comment: If you don’t have administrator rights on the machine, then you can neither install pip nor any PyPI module globally on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run Python as an elevated process in order to have write access to the program files directory where pip will get installed. The simplest and best way to do that is to launch an elevated command prompt `cmd.exe`.

In Windows 7 and later, you can best do that by opening the start menu using the Windows key, and then typing `cmd`. This should give you the command prompt as the first result. Right click on it, and choose *“Run as administrator”*. After accepting the UAC dialogue, this will then start an elevated command prompt with proper write access.

The run the script, then use the following command as explained [in the pip installation manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py):

```
python get-pip.py
```

Of course you need to adjust the path to the `get-pip.py` file. For example if the file is in your downloads folder, you can write the following:

```
python C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\get-pip.py
```

This should the properly install pip for the current Python version.

Note that in order to use pip later, you also need to run it always from an elevated command prompt, as every PyPI module is also installed into the Python directory in your program files (unless you’re using virtual environments of course). So you then need to run e.g. `pip install beautifulsoup4`. If `pip.exe` is not in your path, which likely be the case, you can also run pip using the Python executable like this: `python -m pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. i have a few problem areas though . when i run python get-pip.py in the command prompt , i get error: 'python ' is not an exteranl or internal command. please help

Comment: Then Python also isn’t in your PATH. You can try using `py` instead of `python` (i.e. `py get-pip.py`) if you have the Python launcher on your system; if that also doesn’t work, you need to specify the full path to the Python executable, e.g. something like `C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe get-pip.py` or whatever the path to your Python installation is (you will have to figure that out yourself).

Comment: hi. i added a third image to demonstrate my issue. i specified the right path in the command prompt to run get-pip.py.this time no error message(thank u @poke ), but no results are displayed either.

Comment: You need to run `python.exe` not `pythonw.exe` (note the `w`).

Comment: i got the path address from IDLE using commands print sys.executable. is that not right??.

Comment: IDLE runs `pythonw`, yes. But you still need to use `python.exe` here.

Comment: If you find yourself frequently needing an elevated command prompt, you can avoid the routine of "run as administrator" and agreeing to the consent dialog by creating a task that runs elevated, e.g.  `schtasks /create /tn ecmd /tr "cmd.exe /t:0E /k 'cd %USERPROFILE% & title Command Prompt'" /ru %USERNAME% /rp /it /rl highest /sc once /st 00:00 /sd 01/01/1900`. Then run it using `schtasks /run /i /tn ecmd`.  You can set this command in an ecmd.lnk shortcut, or ecmd.bat. For the former, add .LNK to `PATHEXT` to avoid having to type the extension. Put the shortcut/batch in a `PATH` directory.